# Remove file from amended commit

Tags: git, version-control

I pushed a commit to a repo where I accidentally added a file. Nobody else has merged from the remote repo so I can rewrite history. But when I remove file(unstage, not remove from source control, or disk) from local commit, I am unable to push changes. git push shows Everything up-to-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I did something similar to what Colin and ydroneaud have suggested,

The answer was to use

```
git push +sa1:sa1
```

where sa1 is my branch. This forces to push even 'nothing'.

Answer (score 16):

Here you go:

```
git checkout HEAD~ -- path/to/your/file
git add path/to/your/file
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

---

```
git diff -p HEAD~ -- path/to/your/file | git apply -R
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

---

```
git reset HEAD~ -- path/to/your/file
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

Comment: I did this. The problem was that the changes weren't pushed to the remote repo.

Comment: Note: When commit metadata does not need to preserved (in the usual case) `-C HEAD` can be replaced by `--no-edit`

Comment: the bottom two miss the adding of the file inbetween

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
git rm --cached <yourfile>
git commit --amend
git push -f
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the file from tracking, just from the commit.

Comment: @sa1 there's no concept of tracking in git, your file either is or isn't in your last commit, that's all. The other option is just leaving the file there but with no content or part removed. Git is just a "stupid content tracker" made by a "filesystem guy". ;)

Comment: @KurzedMetal There is a concept of tracked files. What you do here is removing the file from the tracked files, what he wants to do is removing the changes made on a file in a commit.

Comment: @ColinHebert Barring the matter of force push reportedly not conveying deletions, this works to do precisely what the original poster requested in the simplest way: To unstage a file and amend the commit.  The file can then be added in a later commit.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to rewrite the full commit, try to use

```
git reset HEAD^
git add <files to be part of the commit>
# or git add -pu
git commit -C <previous commit number>
```

Before doing this you will need to keep the last commit number to able to reuse the commit message/date/author.

Comment: I did something similar. The problem was that I was unable to push those changes to the remote repo.

Answer (score 3):

With these two commands you immediately revert all changes to `FILE` in the last commit *without* changing its (working tree) contents:

```sh
git reset HEAD~ "FILE"
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Simplified based on the answer at https://superuser.com/a/567550

Note that this will add all currently staged changes into the commit as well, so you might want to run `git restore --staged -- $(git rev-parse --git-dir)` beforehand.

---

Previous solution derived from the answer of @ColinHebert

```sh
git diff -p HEAD~ -- "FILE" | git apply --reverse --cached
git commit --amend --no-edit
```