# Move a single file out of a git commit and place it in separate git commit

Tags: git

I have committed certain number of file in git e.g.

Commit 1 contains:

- file1
- file2[renamed]
- file3
- file4

Now I want to move file2[renamed] file to be placed in different commit without disturbing other files. Is it possible in git?

Comment: Is "commit 1" the HEAD commit?

Comment: yes.. even that is not merged. Before merge i want to split it into two

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove file from amended commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124593/remove-file-from-amended-commit). in particular, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10127051/4233593) demonstrates what you want nicely, but you'll need to reset for both `file2` and `file2[renamed]`

Answer (score 2):

1. reset with the soft flag to keep the staged changes
2. reset the renamed files individually
3. make new commits

---

initialize repository

```
jeff ~ $ mkdir tg
jeff ~ $ cd tg
jeff tg $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/administrator/tg/.git/
jeff tg (master #) $ touch file1
jeff tg (master #) $ touch file2a
jeff tg (master #) $ touch file3
jeff tg (master #) $ touch file4
jeff tg (master #) $ git add .
jeff tg (master #) $ git commit -m "init"
[master (root-commit) c4668aa] init
 4 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file1
 create mode 100644 file2a
 create mode 100644 file3
 create mode 100644 file4
```

make changes and commit 1

```
jeff tg (master) $ mv file2a file2
jeff tg (master *) $ echo amendment >> file1
jeff tg (master *) $ echo amendment >> file3
jeff tg (master *) $ echo amendment >> file4
jeff tg (master *) $ git add .
jeff tg (master +) $ git status 
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   file1
        renamed:    file2a -> file2
        modified:   file3
        modified:   file4

jeff tg (master +) $ git commit -m "commit 1"
[master b84034a] commit 1
 4 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
 rename file2a => file2 (100%)
```

soft reset and unstage desired separate changes

```
jeff tg (master) $ git reset --soft HEAD~
jeff tg (master +) $ git reset -- file2a
Unstaged changes after reset:
D       file2a
jeff tg (master *+) $ git status 
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   file1
        new file:   file2
        modified:   file3
        modified:   file4

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    file2a

jeff tg (master *+) $ git reset -- file2
Unstaged changes after reset:
D       file2a
jeff tg (master *+) $ git status 
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   file1
        modified:   file3
        modified:   file4

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    file2a

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        file2
```

make commit with just other changes files (not renamed one)

```
jeff tg (master *+) $ git commit -m "commit 2"
[master 2f29079] commit 2
 3 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
```

now add and commit renamed file

```
jeff tg (master *) $ git add .
jeff tg (master +) $ git status 
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    file2a -> file2

jeff tg (master +) $ git commit -m "commit 3"
[master e2fd651] commit 3
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename file2a => file2 (100%)
```

Answer (score 0):

If commit 1 is the last commit try `git reset --hard HEAD` then `git add`  the changes for file1, file3, and file4 separately.